# Convert DateTime from English to Spanish

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

Does anybody know how to convert a `DateTime` from English to Spanish?

E.g convert:

> Monday, January 01, 2011

into

> Lunes, Enero 01, 2011 ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: January 01, 2011 is a saturday. You probably won't be able to parse this date correctly.

Comment: months in spanish doesn't have capital letters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yyou can use CultureInfo to do this, if you set the current culture in the running thread the date will format in the correct culture
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx

in vb.net

```
    Dim TheDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("January 01 2011")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
MsgBox(TheDate.ToLongDateString)
```

or c#

```
DateTime TheDate = DateTime.Parse("January 01 2011");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
Interaction.MsgBox(TheDate.ToLongDateString());
```

Comment: For those in Puerto Rico, remember that ES is from Spain. Although we use the date in Spanish format, we use the period (.) for decimal numbers (contrary to Spain and other european countries). So in this case, use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-PR"); if you are going to set the current culture in the running thread.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to parse the input into a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) value using an English [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx). Then you can use the [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx) with a Spanish [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) to convert the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) value to a string.

```
var input = "Tuesday, July 26, 2011";
var format = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

var result = dt.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
// result == "martes, julio 26, 2011"
```

Consider that a Spanish user might prefer the Spanish standard format over your custom format though:

```
var result = dt.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
// result == "martes, 26 de julio de 2011"
```

Comment: +1 for noting the `"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"` format is non-standard in Spanish.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail yes is standard: [day] de [month without capital] del [year in 4 digit number]. The correct way is "del" but "de" is also accepted. (I'm spanish university teacher)

Answer (score 3):

Get the DateTime.Now and translate when you need.

```
private DateTime lastConnection = DateTime.Now;
String dateString =lastConnection.ToString("dd") +" de "+ lastConnection.ToString("MMMM",new CultureInfo("es-ES"))
```